# Surprising behavior of TypeScript generics

Tags: typescript

I was playing with generics and was expecting to get compilation errors in two places in the code below, but I didn't get any errors. Am I using TypeScript generics in a wrong way or there is another reason for not catching the erroneous function invocations?

```
class Person {

}

class Employee extends Person {

}

interface Payable<T> {
  pay(arg: T): T
}

class C implements Payable<Employee> {
  pay(e: Employee) { return e;}
}

const c = new C();

c.pay(123);   // why no errors here?

function doStuff<T extends Employee>(param: T) {

}

doStuff(123);  // why no errors here?
```

You can try this example in the Playground at http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Person%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Employee%20extends%20Person%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Payable%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20pay(arg%3A%20T)%3A%20T%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20C%20implements%20Payable%3CEmployee%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20pay(e%3A%20Employee)%20%7B%20return%20e%3B%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20c%20%3D%20new%20C()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ac.pay(123)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20doStuff%3CT%20extends%20Employee%3E(param%3A%20T)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AdoStuff(123)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A

Thanks

Comment: why do you think it should error? what do you expect to happen?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-all-types-assignable-to-empty-interfaces

Comment: I was expecting an error stating that the method pay() has to be called with the parameter of type Employee.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen But my interface is not empty

Comment: The `Employee` class is empty.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen Thank you Matt!  Turn your comments into an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `Employee` class has no members, any value is structurally compatible with an `Employee` and can be passed where an `Employee` is expected.  See [this FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-all-types-assignable-to-empty-interfaces).